# Is it possible to change filters by category?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to be able to change the filters that appear depending on the category selected. Important to note that some categories may have the same products and that there may be multiple attribute sets so I can't do it by product.

I need to be able to say "for this category, display these filters"...anyone come across anything like that? I've seen some code changes involving hard coding category ID's but I need it to be user friendly (i.e. it won't just be me updating) so I'm guessing an extension would be useful but I can't find one anywhere that does this!

Your help as always much appreciated :-)